# 404 error for /saml2/idp/ after upgrading Kentor.AuthServices to Sustainsys.Saml2

Tags: owin, sustainsys-saml2

Had things working with Kentor.AuthServices.Owin 0.18.0 and typically this traffic log.

```
200 GET https://some-saml2-idp.com/saml2/idp/SSO_1..39%3D&RelayState=Os..j
302 POST https://demo.local/AuthServices/Acs
200 GET for the set RedirectUri
```

After upgrading to Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin 2.2.0 I get this traffic log...

```
200 GET https://some-saml2-idp.com/saml2/idp/SSO_1a7f5..sy%2Fh9rebTw%3D%3D&RelayState=1M..3c
302 POST https://demo.local/AuthServices/Acs
303 GET https://demo.local/login?error=access_denied
200 GET https://some-saml2-idp.com/saml2/idp/SSO_1a7f..NfLr6E299uPwE%3D&RelayState=cS..L
302 POST https://demo.local/AuthServices/Acs
404 GET https://demo.local/saml2/idp/SSO_1..39?SAMLRequest=hZ..bTw==&RelayState=1M..c&error=access_denied
```

I've tried clearing cookies everywhere and tried to find any "own" code responsible for the error or the error parameter.

I would prefer if I could get things working for both my branches without changing anything on the IDP side.

My Web.config has the following structure...

```
<sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://demo.local/AuthServices"
        returnUrl="https://demo.local"
        publicOrigin="https://demo.local"
        modulePath="/AuthServices">
    <serviceCertificates>
        <add fileName="~/somename.pfx"
            use="Signing" />
    </serviceCertificates>
    <identityProviders>
        <add entityId="My-IDP"
            allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true"
            loadMetadata="true"
            metadataLocation="https://some-saml2-idp.com/metadata" />
    </identityProviders>
</sustainsys.saml2>
```

And my Owin startup...

```
var defaultSignInAsAuthType = "Cookies";

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(defaultSignInAsAuthType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = defaultSignInAsAuthType,
    ReturnUrlParameter  = "returnUrl",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
    LogoutPath = new PathString("/logout")
});

var saml2Options = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(true);
app.UseSaml2Authentication(saml2Options);
app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);

AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name;
```

What am I missing to mimic the behaviour of the older package setup?

Comment: Looks like the first access to /AuthServices/Acs results in some kind of error. Please enable katana logging and see if that reveals anything.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Got further when adding minIncomingSigningAlgorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" as log showed me.

Comment: Yes, that's another default setting that has changed (to the better from a security perspective) does it work now? In that case I'll add that as an answer to the question for the next person with same problem.

Comment: Yes! After that and adding a HttpModule that triggered my ClaimsAuthenticationManager I was back to the same status as with the old setup I hope. Also upgraded .NET Framework to 4.7.2 and many of the packages in the solution.

Comment: Good - I summarized in an answer. And please review that HttpModule - you're doing something strange. Use the `AcsCommandResultCreated` notification instead of the ClaimsAuthenticationManager.

Comment: Yes, I will work on removing the Module. For some reason they didn't put the transformed claims in the OWIN AuthenticationTicket but transform at the start of every request :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of breaking changes between those releases that might trigger problems.

The Katana logging will contain error messages. Some things that are relevant are:

1. The mininum accepted incoming signing algorithm is now by default SHA-256. Can be set through the `minIncomingSigninAlgorithm` config.
2. The module path (base path for all endpoints) now defaults to `/Saml2` instead of `/AuthServices`. In the question, it is already correctly configured to `/AuthServices` to be backwards compatible.
3. The ClaimsAuthenticationManager is no longer supported on 2.X as it no longer uses the System.IdentityModel token handlers. Use the `AcsCommandResultCreated` notification to modify the created identity instead.